# How can I solve this systems of differential equation and show a plot?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, difference-equations

$$ \frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dt} = 1 - u \mathrm e^{\epsilon(8q-1)}  $$
$$ \frac{\mathrm dq}{\mathrm dt} = u \mathrm e^{\epsilon (q-1)} - q $$

$ 0 \leq \epsilon \leq 0.1 $

$u(0) = 0$ and $  q(0)=0$

I try whit this but I can't

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DSolveSystemsOfNonlinearODEs.html

```
system = {u'[t] + u[t] E^(\[Epsilon] (q - 1)) == 1, u[0] == 0, 
   q'[t] - u[t] E^(\[Epsilon] (q - 1)) + q[t] == 0, q[0] == 0};


sol = DSolve[system, {u, q}, t]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some of the code you've tried to solve this with so far?

Comment: Sure

system = {u'[t] + u[t] E^(\[Epsilon] (q - 1)) == 1, u[0] == 0, 
   q'[t] - u[t] E^(\[Epsilon] (q - 1)) + q[t] == 0, q[0] == 0};


sol = DSolve[system, {u, q}, t]

Comment: Use `q[t]` instead of `q` in your equations

Comment: look at the images, it did not work.

Comment: `Clear[q]`, and use `q[0] == 0` instead of `q[0] = 0`.

Comment: The command sol = ParametricNDSolve[ system, {u[t], q[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, {\[Epsilon] }] should work.

Comment: `NDSolve` is certainly able to do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Clear[Evaluate[Context[] <> "*"]];
Clear[sol, u, q];
Manipulate[
 sol = NDSolve[{
    u'[t] + u[t]*Exp[\[Epsilon] (q[t] - 1)] == 1,
    q'[t] - u[t]*Exp[\[Epsilon] (q[t] - 1)] + q[t] == 0,
    q[0] == 0,
    u[0] == 0
    },
   {u, q},
   {t, 0, 60}];
 Plot[{u[t],q[t]} /.sol, {t, 0, 60}],
 {{\[Epsilon], 0}, 0, 1}
 ]
```

[image]

**EDIT 1**

Can you try this? It takes a long time to solve it in my computer. Note that in `Mathematica` `e` is represented by `Exp[]`.

```
DSolve[{
  u'[t] + u[t]*Exp[\[Epsilon] (q[t] - 1)] == 1,
  q'[t] - u[t]*Exp[\[Epsilon] (q[t] - 1)] + q[t] == 0,
  q[0] == 0,
  u[0] == 0
  },
 {u, q}, t]
```

Comment: thanks soo much, i try whir Ruge Kutta Method

$$E7 = NDSolve[{u'[t] + u[t] E^(\[Epsilon] (q[t] - 1)) - 1 == 0, 
    u[0] == 0,  q'[t] - u[t] E^(\[Epsilon] (q[t] - 1)) + q[t] == 0, 
    q[0] == 0}, {u, q}, {t, 0, 6}, 
   Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}];$$